# Sorting list of strings by a character

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I got the following assignment:

> For a given list of strings write a function that returns a sorted list with all strings starting with the character `x` at the beginning (define two lists)

I stuck here:

```
set_words_list = ["argentinax", "football", "ss", "poxland", "axmerica"]
set_words_list.sort(key=str("x"))
print(set_words_list)
```

And then error pops out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/5SortList/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    set_words_list.sort(key=str("x"))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

It is my first time coding in Python, and I have no clue where to go from there.
On top of that, according to the task one needs to use 2 lists, yet I don't know how it can help me.

Comment: `key` must be a function that returns the part of the elements to compare when sorting.

Comment: There are no strings that begin with "x" in your list.  Otherwise you could use: `set_words_list.sort(key=lambda s:(s[:1]!="x",s))`

Comment: It's not clear what's meant by "returns a sorted list with all strings starting with the character x" (especially since no words in your list starts with x).  Can you show your desired output for `set_words_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to split the input into two lists. One contains the elements that start with `x`, the other contains the rest. That's what the instructions meant by "define two lists".

Then sort each of these lists and concatenate them.

```
x_words = []
nox_words = []
for word in set_words_list:
    if word.startswith("x"):
        x_words.append(word)
    else:
        nox_words.append(word)

result = sorted(x_words) + sorted(nox_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.sort(reverse=True|False, key=myFunc)

reverse --> Optional. reverse=True will sort the list descending. Default is reverse=False
key-->  Optional. A function to specify the sorting criteria(s)
```

In below code we are passing `myFunc` to the key part of the sort function.
Function returns  `not e.startswith('x')` since True == 1. This will sort the words starting with `'x'`.

```
def myFunc(e):
    return  not e.startswith('x')

set_words_list = ["argentinax", "football", "ss", "poxland", "axmerica", 'xx']

set_words_list.sort(key=myFunc)
print(set_words_list)
```

Comment: `key` doesn't specify the sorting criteria. It extracts the part of the input that should be compared between elements.

Comment: ok. what do you think I should use instead to solve the task?

Comment: It seems like you're just showing the documentation of the `sort()` method, not explaining how to solve the given problem.

Comment: @Barmar Actually I was working on above code. I cant figure out why it is not working.Can you please help?

Comment: Now you're just sorting by whether they start with `x`, but not sorting by the rest of the word within each group.

Comment: Also, `True == 1`, so you need to return `not e.startswith("x")`

Comment: @Barmar The question doesn't ask for sorting by the rest of the word, does it?

Comment: That's how I interpreted it. Sort the names, but put the X names first.

Answer (score 0):

```
set_words_list = ["argentinax", "football", "ss", "poxland", 'xamerica' ,"axmerica"]

x_first_letter = sorted([x for x in set_words_list if x[0]=='x'])
nox_first_letter = sorted([x for x in set_words_list if not x[0]=='x'])
```

Comment: It's working now :) It's very close to Barmar's solution, but a bit shorter code-wise.

Comment: *"sorted on word length"* is not true.